# react native TypeError (..) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I want to display an image and the according text from an object chosen randomly from an array.

Basically that's the chain I plan on using to get both the name and the image:
ingredient <- ingredientArray <- getRandomIngredient <- getIngredientImage (& getIngredientName)

I'm sure there is something basic I just don't get about object oriented programming, but I can't get it to work.

ingredientArray:

```
const ingredient1 = new Ingredient("green salad", require('./app/components/img/base/green_salad.jpg'));
const ingredient2 = new Ingredient("mixed salad", require('./app/components/img/base/mixed_salad.jpg'));
var ingredientArray = ["ingredient1", "ingredient2"]
```

getRandomIngredient:

```
function getRandomIngredient (arr){
  if (arr && arr.length) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
  }
}
```

class Ingredient:

```
function Ingredient (ingredientName, ingredientImage){
  this.ingredientName = ingredientName;
  this.ingredientImage = ingredientImage;

  Ingredient.prototype.getIngredientName = function(){
    return this.ingredientName;
  }

  Ingredient.prototype.getIngredientImage = function(){
    return this.ingredientImage;
  }
}
```

What I would like to do:

```
<Image source = {getRandomIngredient(ingredientArray).getIngredientImage()}
```

But I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: getRandomIngredient(...).getIngredientImage is not a function
```

If I call the function getIngredientImage() directly, I get a working result:

```
<Image source = {base1.getIngredientImage()} />
```

Comment: Can you post your entire component JS file?

Comment: To mark a question as solved, one does not need to edit the title on Stack Overflow - there is a proper acceptance system. Click the tick/check mark adjacent to the answer you liked most. It is not mandatory, but it is nice, as it encourages helpful people to help again.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `getIngredientImage` method because `getRandomIngredient(ingredientArray)` doesn't return an instance of `Ingredient`. Because `ingredientArray` is an array of strings, not `Ingredient` instances.

It should be:

```
var ingredientArray = [ingredient1, ingredient2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the variables to your "ingredientArray" instead of the "string" identifiers that you are using for your constants. IE change

```
var ingredientArray = ["ingredient1", "ingredient2"]
```

to

```
var ingredientArray = [ingredient1, ingredient2]
```